# File Importing Sequence changed using parfor (different results using parfor and for)

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have an issue with the file importing when converting my for loop into parfor and would appreciate any help I can get.
The structure of my code is as following:

```
myFolder = '../Test';

if option1 == 1
    ext = 'EW';
    filePattern1 = fullfile(myFolder, '*.EW1'); % input motion
    datFiles1 = dir(filePattern1);
    filePattern2 = fullfile(myFolder, '*.EW2'); % surface motion
    datFiles2 = dir(filePattern2);
elseif option1 == 2
    ext = 'NS';
    filePattern1 = fullfile(myFolder, '*.NS1'); % input motion
    datFiles1 = dir(filePattern1);
    filePattern2 = fullfile(myFolder, '*.NS2'); % surface motion
    datFiles2 = dir(filePattern2);
end


parfor k = 1:length(datFiles1)

  baseFileName1 = datFiles1(k).name;
  baseFileName2 = datFiles2(k).name;
  fullFileName1 = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName1);
  fullFileName2 = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName2);

%display file importing sequence
  fprintf(1, 'Now processing %s\n', baseFileName1);
  record1 = load(baseFileName1);
  fprintf(1, 'Now processing %s\n', baseFileName2);
  record2 = load(baseFileName2);
 npts2 = length(record2(:,1)); 

     %this is the end of file importing part and the following is to process the imported data, and as that is not relevant to this issue, I didn’t show them.
end
```

The datFiles1 and datFiles2 look like this:

[image]

And datFiles2 goes with the same sequence except with EW2 extensions. 
Then it should display as in Filename1.EW1, Filename1.EW2, Filename2.EW1, Filename2.EW2, Filename3.EW1, Filename3.EW2, Filename4.EW1, Filename4.EW2 … 
As like this: (if I only use for loop)

However, if I use parfor, the sequence is messed up as it seems like it randomly imports some file and then follows the sequence again
  [enter image description here][3]
The first 4 lines are right. Then the 6th line starts to show an error when it should have been MYGH050008281720.EW2

[image]

The key is to process each pair of EW1, EW2 files(with same filenames) in a loop. Is there any other way to import files in parfor? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to include image 3.

Comment: If the order matters, you should not use `parfor`. `parfor` uses multiple threads to calculate the result of different loops at the same time. Why do you think this will be a problem for you? Note that each thread has its own local variables (`record1` and `record2`).

Comment: I'm only limited to upload two pictures.

Comment: As processing each pair of EW1 and EW2 (same file names) takes a long time so I wanted to use parfor instead of for loop. Yes in each thread, the local variables will be reset. Is there a way to control the order of parfor? Thanks!

Comment: No, but do you really need it?

Comment: yes considering the amount of files needed to process and each loop takes a long time

Comment: I mean, do you really need that to control the order of parfor?